# Need help finding syntax error in SQL code

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I have been trying to follow along with a SQL tutorial on YT. Every time I try to run this command, it gives me this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 5

```
CREATE TABLE student (
student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
major VARCHAR(20),
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES (1, 'Jack', 'Biology');
```

Comment: You have a comma before the `)`.

Comment: Id like to add I am following the 4 hour tutorial on YT (by freecodecamp I believe) and in this lesson we are using PopSql. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I got rid of the comma before the ).. I am also getting an error message that says: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: It works fine when the comma is removed: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: You must have left something out of the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Maybe you appened AUTO_INCREMENT for student_id column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
drop table student;

CREATE TABLE student (
  student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  major VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO student (student_id, name, major) VALUES (1, 'Jack', 'Biology');
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you all for the help!